# Create geom_tile plot with two dataframes

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Below is R code that attempts to create a heat map using geom_tile. Within my plot, I need to plot an outline of a box and a separate pair of x//y coordinates (titled platelocside and platelocheight in the code) that also have a fill (titled exitspeed in code) to complete the heat map. Here is the current structure of my data frame that I want to plot (labeled as "df" in the code).

```
structure(list(platelocheight = c(2.594, 3.803, 3.254, 3.599, 
3.617, 3.297, 2.093, 3.611, 2.842, 3.316, 2.872, 3.228, 3.633, 
4.28, 3.309, 2.8, 2.632, 3.754, 2.207, 3.604, 3.443, 2.188, 3.452, 
2.553, 3.382, 3.067, 2.986, 2.785, 2.567, 3.804), platelocside = c(0.059, 
-1.596, -0.65, -0.782, -0.301, -0.104, 0.057, -0.807, 0.003, 
1.661, 0.088, -0.32, -1.115, -0.146, -0.364, -0.952, 0.254, 0.109, 
-0.671, -0.803, -0.212, -0.069, -0.09, -0.472, 0.434, 0.337, 
0.723, 0.508, -0.197, -0.635), exitspeed = c(69.891, 73.352, 
83.942, 85.67, 79.454, 85.277, 81.078, 73.573, 77.272, 59.263, 
97.343, 91.436, 76.264, 83.479, 47.576, 84.13, 60.475, 61.093, 
84.54, 69.959, 88.729, 88.019, 82.18, 83.684, 86.296, 90.605, 
79.945, 59.899, 62.522, 77.75)), .Names = c("platelocheight", 
"platelocside", "exitspeed"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

When I run the code, I am able to get the outline of the box in my output, but the other data frame (title df) did not plot. Does anyone know who to use geom_tile that will be able to plot two separate dataframes? Thanks in advance!

```
library(RODBC)
library(ggplot2)


con=odbcConnect('ID',uid='username', pwd = 'password')

df=sqlQuery(con,"select platelocheight, platelocside, exitspeed from tm_sample where pitchcall='InPlay' 
and exitspeed is not null")

topKzone <- 3.5
botKzone <- 1.6
inKzone <- -0.95
outKzone <- 0.95
kZone <- data.frame(
  x=c(inKzone, inKzone, outKzone, outKzone, inKzone),
  y=c(botKzone, topKzone, topKzone, botKzone, botKzone)
)

ggplot(kZone, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_tile(data=df, aes(x=platelocside, y=platelocheight, fill= exitspeed)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  geom_path(lwd=1.5, col="black") +
  coord_fixed()
```

Comment: Try adding `inherit.aes = FALSE` into your `geom_tile()` line for a start. But to get more specific help, you may want to provide the result of `dput(df)` (or at least `dput(header(df))` so we know what it's like.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Z.Lin! Unfortunately, the inherit.aes addition did not make a difference. I provided the result of the df in case you have any other ideas. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that not in the use of two dataframes, but rather in the implementation of `geom_tile()` itself.

If you swap for `geom_tile` for a different geom, say `geom_point` or `geom_hex` for example, you'd see that the plot is rendered perfectly:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(kZone, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_hex(data=df, aes(x=platelocside, y=platelocheight, col=exitspeed)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  geom_path(lwd=1.5, col="black") +
  coord_fixed()
```

Produces this:
[image]

#### Understanding `geom_tile`

`geom_tile` is not a good choice with your data because you're using a continuous x and y scale and that makes it a more viable choice with something like a scatterplot as compared to a heatmap-like graphic.

You can see an example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(gear), y=as.factor(cyl), fill=hp))+
    geom_tile()
```

[image]

Compared to when you were to call it on two continuous variables:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, fill=hp))+
    geom_tile()
```

You'll get tiles that are so small in effect it looks like nothing was plotted.

Going back to your question, the `df` that you're using has `platelocside` and `platelocheight` both as numeric, continuous variables. That makes `geom_hex` a less-than-ideal choice. If you **do insist** on using `geom_tile` then I would use one of the two solutions:

**Solution 1**

Use `col` instead of `fill` to get points instead of tiles (since the `x` and `y` are not factor variables)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(kZone, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_tile(data=df, aes(x=platelocside, y=platelocheight, col=exitspeed), size=4) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  geom_path(lwd=1.5, col="black") +
  coord_fixed()
```

**Solution 2**

Make `x` and `y` a factor variable:

```
df$h <- round(df$platelocheight)
df$s <- round(df$platelocside)

ggplot(kZone, aes(x,y)) +
  geom_tile(data=df, aes(x=s, y=h, fill=exitspeed)) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral") +
  geom_path(lwd=1.5, col="black") +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

Comment: That's great advice, thanks @onlyphantom! I appreciate you taking the time to write and explain all of that! Quick follow-up question. For this type of data in the baseball industry, heat maps are very popular when portraying this type of information. Would you have any recommendations on geom packages if I wanted to create a chart like what shows up in this link? http://baseballanalysts.com/rhb_rhp_copy.png

Comment: No problem Nate, always happy to help. I took a look at the png and off the top of my head I would recommend you take a closer look at density charts offered in ggplot. Do a search on `stat_density_2d()` and that may just be what you need. Good luck!

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Hey onlyphantom! I took your advice and have attempted to build a `stat_density_2d()` plot, but I'm having an issue with the fill variable. Would you mind taking a look at my most recent post if you have some time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865464/adding-a-3rd-variable-to-a-stat-density-2d-plot Thanks so much!